# MS Azure cannot find webspace for subscription

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

I have a resourcegroup in Microsoft Azure with some resources on it, nothing strange, some VMs, databases, storage accounts, and a virtual network. So far no web apps or app service plans.

I am trying to add a app service plan with a simple powershell command:

```
New-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name "testsvcplan" -Location "North Europe"
-ResourceGroupName "mygroup" -Tier Free
```

which results in the following error:

> Cannot find Web space mygroup-NorthEuropewebspace for subscription xxx-xxx-xxx.

Getting the same error when trying to add an app service plan through the portal and cannot find much info about this error or Azure Web space.
Although it works fine when using other resourcegroups.

**What is a Azure web space and what could cause this error with my resource group?**

Comment: can you check your client `C:\Users\{youraccountname}\.azure` and check if the spaces.{someGuid} file exist or not.

Comment: I cannot find any .azure folder. What would cause the .azure folder to be created ?

Comment: It is hidden files, you should show the hidden files, you can follow this to modify it.https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files

Comment: Yes, I am always showing hidden files, did a powershell search for the .azure dir on the c:/users folder but no results. It doesn't exists. What would create it and what is it used for?

Comment: Which version of your Azure powershell?

Comment: please run this command `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` to get the version of your azure powerhshell,

Comment: Running version 3.3.0. But the local powershell version doesn't explain why I get the same error though the portal :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59728/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-andreas).

Answer (score 0):

So, after almost two weeks of help from Microsoft Azure support, they cannot say why my resourcegroup is missing it's webspace. We ended up moving resources to another resource group using [the following guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources) instead.

Now I know this isn't really an answer. But if anyone could be able to solve it, Microsoft Azure support should, but it seems like a dead end.